# rufus + puma + heroku warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma, rufus-scheduler

I'm running a rails app on heroku, I have two web dynos.
How can I remove the ! WARNING: Detected 1 Thread(s) started in app boot: warning?

My puma.rb file:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do |worker_number| 
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

The logs:

```
2016-09-03T14:21:24.742960+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:53786
2016-09-03T14:21:24.743135+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] ! WARNING: Detected 1 Thread(s) started in app boot:
2016-09-03T14:21:24.743181+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] ! #<Thread:0x007f382b59fca8@/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.2.2/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:563 sleep> - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.2.2/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:571:in `sleep'
2016-09-03T14:21:24.743257+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Use Ctrl-C to stop
2016-09-03T14:21:24.754941+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Worker 0 (pid: 7) booted, phase: 0
2016-09-03T14:21:24.756269+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Worker 1 (pid: 20) booted, phase: 0
2016-09-03T14:21:25.525174+00:00 app[web.2]: ** [NewRelic][2016-09-03 14:21:25 +0000 web.2 (18)] INFO : Doing deferred dependency-detection before Rack startup
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. Stop using rufus-scheduler. It's using threads, that's what is causing your warning.

Look at:

```
2016-09-03T14:21:24.743181+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] ! 
<Thread:0x007f382b59fca8@
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.2.2/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:563
sleep> -
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.2.2/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:571
:in `sleep'
```

Rufus-scheduler clearly is the cause of the warning.

Cf https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/issues/213

Now there is another way to look at the thing: the warning is not emitted by rufus-scheduler, it's emitted by Puma. There's probably a way to disable the warning, but that's a question for people with knowledge of Puma.

Comment: well that not an answer what if i have other gems using threads (activerecord 5.2.4.2, elastic apm ....) example :        
 ```15437] ! #<Thread:0x00007f7f2e2a9ec8@/Users/almokhtar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:299 sleep> '```